# Problem with jQuery plugin TinySort

Tags: jquery, list, sorting, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to sort a list with the help of jQuery and the [TinySort](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/)-plugin, and it works good but one thing is not working as i want. My Code is:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
        <title>TinySort problem</title> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://so.volmar.se/oldstatic/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://so.volmar.se/oldstatic/jquery.tinysort.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function pktsort(way){
    if($("div#paket>ul>li.sortdiv>a#s_abc").text() == "A-S"){
        $("div#paket>ul>li.sortdiv>a#s_abc").text("S-A");
        $("div#paket ul li.sortable").tsort("",{place:"org",returns:true,order:"desc"});
    }else{
        $("div#paket>ul>li.sortdiv>a#s_abc").text("A-S");
        $("div#paket ul li.sortable").tsort("",{place:"org",returns:true,order:"asc"});
    }
}
</script>

    </head> 
<body> 
<div id="paket" title="Paket"> 
    <ul class="rounded"> 
        <li class="sortdiv">Sort: <a href="#" onclick="pktsort();" class="active_sort" id="s_abc">A-S</a></li> 
        <li class="sortable">Almost Famous</li> 
        <li class="sortable">Children of Men</li> 
        <li class="sortable">Coeurs</li> 
        <li class="sortable">Colossal Youth</li> 
        <li class="sortable">Demonlover</li> 
        <li class="sortable">Femme Fatale</li> 
        <li class="sortable">I'm Not There</li> 
        <li class="sortable">In the City of Sylvia</li> 
        <li class="sortable">Into the Wild</li> 
        <li class="sortable">Je rentre à la maison</li> 
        <li class="sortable">King Kong</li> 
        <li class="sortable">Little Miss Sunshine</li> 
        <li class="sortable">Man on Wire</li> 
        <li class="sortable">Milk</li> 
        <li class="sortable">Monsters Inc.</li> 
        <li class="sortable">My Winnipeg</li> 
        <li class="sortable">Ne touchez pas la hache</li> 
        <li class="sortable">Nói albinói</li> 
        <li class="sortable">Regular Lovers</li> 
        <li class="sortable">Shaun of the Dead</li> 
        <li class="sortable">Silent Light</li> 
        <li class="addmore"><b>This text is not supposed to move</b></li>
    </ul> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

you can try it out at: http://www.volmar.se/list-prob.html

**MY PROBLEM IS:**
I don't want the `<li class="addmore">` to move above all the `<li class="sortable">`-elements when i press the sort-link. i wan't it to always be in the bottom.

you can find documentation of the TinySort plugin [here](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/). i've tried loads of combinations with place and returns propertys but i just can't get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After sorting, could you append the one you want on the bottom to the bottom? ie.

```
$('#paket .rounded .addmore').appendTo('#paket .rounded');
```